# How can I get full resolution out of different generations of cinema displays?

Tags: macos, display, thunderbolt, cinema-display

I have a newer thunderbolt display and an older Apple Cinema HD display hooked up to my retina macbook pro (15 inch, early 2013, 1 GB GeForce GT 650M graphics card). The older one is going through a mini-displayport interface to a dvi cable hooked up to a thunderbolt port, while the newer one is on thunderbolt.

However, I've only been able to get as high as 1280 by 800 resolution out of the older monitor. Is there a way to get it to display at a better resolution?

Comment: I've tagged this OSX. Please edit the post to indicate what version of OS you are running.

Comment: What computer model, what os, what graphics card, what monitor, what settings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monitor used dual-link DVI. I was able to get it working using this adapter, and it now displays up to 2560 x 1600:

http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter?afid=p219|GOUS&cid=AOS-US-KWG-PLA

Answer (score 2):

Open sys pref- display

Hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key **before** clicking the Scaled radio button

Now you will see all resolution profiles that are supported for the display.

Something like I have for my Sharp TV

[image: display resolution]

Comment: Is there a difference with holding the option button? It only shows 1280x800 and 1024x640.

Comment: sorry, been busy watching soccer :) if it only shows those 2 than that is all you get with the present driver.